# convenience initializers with derived classes in swift

Tags: swift, initialization, derived-class

I would like to use extension initializers to do transformations on incoming parameters.

I can't find the correct syntax to do this in swift 5.0.  Is this possible?

I want to avoid extension B transforming all of the incoming parameters (in this case from Strings to Ints), but somehow rely on the extension A init.

```
import Foundation

class A
{
    var x : Int

    init (_ x_: Int)
    {
        x = x_;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    var y : Int

    init (_ x_: Int, _ y_: Int)
    {
        y = y_
        super.init(x_);
    }    
}    

extension A
{
    convenience init(_ x_: String) {
        self.init(Int(x_)!);
    }
}

extension B
{
    convenience init(_ x_: String, _ y_: String) {
        super.init(x_);
        self.y = Int(y_)!;
    }
}

let a = A(0)
let b = B(1,2)
let ae = A("3")
let be = B("4","5")

print(a)
print(b)
print(ae)
print(be)
```

Comment: From the Swift book: *"Rule 2: A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same class."* and *"Rule 3: A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated initializer."*.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes.  I'm searching for a way which works despite this.  Like I could possibly use c++ parameters packs to get around this (if they had extensions).  (Use a base class static parse method, bring out arguments, forward them to the same-class-ini)

Comment: See [Class Inheritance and Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID216).

Comment: The convenience init in extension B can only call the init in class B. That's it (of the inits you have at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the closest I've gotten- I would like to get rid of those .0, .1 things, but..  etc.

```
func F1(_ a: Int, _ b: Int)
{
    print(a)
    print(b)
}

let F1P = (1,2)

// this doesn't work, what is the syntax for this?
// can't find how to apply a tuple to a function in swift,
// everywhere says it should "just work"
//F1(F1P)

F1(F1P.0, F1P.1) // lame


class A
{
    var x : Int

    init (_ x_: Int)
    {
        x = x_;
    }

}

class B : A
{
    var y : Int

    init (_ x_: Int, _ y_: Int)
    {
        y = y_
        super.init(x_);
    }
}

extension A
{
    convenience init(sx: String) {
        self.init(A.transform(sx))
    }

    public class func transform(_ x_: String) -> Int
    {
        return (Int(x_)!)
    }
}

extension B
{
    convenience init(sx: String, sy: String) {
        // I want to do this, but it doesn't work
        // self.init(B.transform(sx, sy));

        let p = B.transform(sx, sy)
        self.init(p.0, p.1); // lame
    }

    public class func transform(_ x_: String, _ y_: String) -> (Int, Int)
    {
        return (A.transform(x_), Int(y_)!)
    }
}

let a = A(0)
let b = B(1,2)
let ae = A(sx:"3")
let be = B(sx:"4", sy:"5")

print(a)
print(b)
print(ae)
print(be)
```